# How to display count-down timers at specific times of the day?

Tags: software-rec

I work as a teacher. There are certain routines in my lesson, announced with timed events in Orage, sent to notifications. E.g.:

- Clean Up
- Put Chairs Up

My students requested I put a countdown clock on the screen to warn how much time is left until an event. I use XFce, so this could be either displayed on a panel at the top of the screen, never covered by full screen items, or as a non-clickable, transparent heads-up display that is always present above every window.

E.g.:

- 3:10 until cleanup.
- 6:10 until end of class.

These are not countdowns that are manually activated, but happen at specific times every day, e.g. a 10 minute countdown begins at 3:00 pm and ends at zero at 3:10 pm. I can use `orage` to activate the scripts, but need some way to display the counters and information.

Is there any way to display such count-down timers on the screen?

Comment: A conky widget with [always-on-top](https://superuser.com/a/565837/334516) might do the trick

Comment: All X11 programs can be started, and controlled from bash. And don't use a while loop to do busy waiting, you can use `sleep`.

Comment: Did you already consider a (weekly (Mon - Fri) or daily) cron job might be suitable? I'm sure it could activate the above-mentioned conky widget starting to count down.

Comment: I'm not familiar with how that works.

Comment: @Village: As discussed in the comments here
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/535666/how-to-display-count-down-timers-at-specific-times-of-the-day/542945#comment1009301_542945
when you're talking about `full screen` you actually mean `maximized`,
right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [xfce4-genmon-plugin](https://goodies.xfce.org/projects/panel-plugins/xfce4-genmon-plugin), you can create such a panel widget yourself.

Install the plugin from your distro's repositories. Then create a script which generates the countdown display:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from datetime import date, time, datetime

now = datetime.now()

def show_countdown(target, event):
    if now >= target:
        print(("{} NOW!").format(event))
        return

    time_left = target - now
    min, sec = divmod(time_left.seconds, 60)
    hrs, min = divmod(min, 60)
    print("{} in {}:{:02}:{:02}".format(event, hrs, min, sec))  

show_countdown(
    datetime.combine(date.today(), time(10, 25)),
    "Cleanup"
)
show_countdown(
    datetime.combine(date.today(), time(10, 30)),
    "Class ends"
)
```

Modify it as you see fit, save it in some unobtrusive place and grant it execution permission (`chmod +x`). Then add a "Generic monitor" item to your panel. Point the panel item to your script and configure a suitable refresh interval (if you removed seconds display, you should probably leave it at 30 seconds to save power/performance). And there you have it.

Comment: So does `xfce4-genmon-plugin` simply run whatever script is selected, printing what would have been displayed in the terminal, but instead on the panel?

Comment: That's right. There is also some formatting markup available, described on the page I linked.

Answer (score 6):

Python with ‍‍`tkinter` outputs the fastest and easiest way to create the GUI applications and widget. Creating a GUI using `tkinter` is an easy task.

You just need to use the following command to install the `tkinter`

`apt-get install python-tk python3-tk`

For Fedora users, use the following command.

`dnf install python-tkinter python3-tkinter`

This is a simple script for countdown with `tkinter`, always ontop and transparent:

```
import tkinter as tk
from datetime import datetime, time

def dateDiffInSeconds(date1, date2):
    timedelta = date2 - date1
    return timedelta.days * 24 * 3600 + timedelta.seconds

def daysHoursMinutesSecondsFromSeconds(seconds):
    minutes, seconds = divmod(seconds, 60)
    hours, minutes = divmod(minutes, 60)
    days, hours = divmod(hours, 24)
    return (days, hours, minutes, seconds)

def counter_label(label):
    leaving_date = datetime.strptime('2022-01-01 01:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')    #end time to count down
    def count():
        now = datetime.now()
        counter = daysHoursMinutesSecondsFromSeconds(dateDiffInSeconds(now, leaving_date))
        label.config(text=str("%d days, %d hours, %d minutes, %d seconds" % counter))
        label.after(1000, count)
    count()


root = tk.Tk()
root.attributes('-topmost', True)       #always on top
root.title("Counting Seconds")          #title
label = tk.Label(root, fg="dark green") #font color
label.pack()
counter_label(label)
button = tk.Button(root, text='Stop', width=25, command=root.destroy)   #stop button
button.pack()
root.wait_visibility(root)
root.wm_attributes('-alpha',0.5)    # transparent windows  0.1 - 1
root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: I use `fluxbox` and this solution doesn't work for me.  A window
titled `Counting seconds` shows up in the left upper corner but it's
blocked by full-screen windows. For example, press F11 in Firefox or
Evince and notice that the window is not visible.

Comment: I've run `xfce4` inside `Xephyr` and `tkinter` windows is blocked by full-screen apps as well. So I think this answer is wrong and doesn't answer OP's question.

Comment: If you press f11 in firefox you can't see any other things even xfce clock and other xfce plugins. so all the other answers is wrong too. i think by full screen she/he means maximized windows becuse she/he said 'this could be either displayed on a panel at the top of the screen,'  @Arkadiusz Drabczyk

Comment: `i think by full screen she/he means maximized windows` - I think that too but in that case the question should be rephrased.

Comment: Yes, it needs to be visible even when a window is full screen, so either it is a transparent layer or on a panel, but some settings must be changed so the panel is always visible and not covered by full screen apps if a solution using the panel is used.

Comment: If you wanna  see the panel in a full screen app there is no need to change everything, you can maximize the window then you can see the panel and window together :-) @Village

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways and widgets to have a timer or countdown, but considering you are using xfce and want something graphical on the panel, you might want to try [xfce4-timer-plugin](https://goodies.xfce.org/projects/panel-plugins/xfce4-timer-plugin).

It does require xfce >= 4.6 though. I don't know which version of xfce you are running, but this plugin might very well work for your needs.

The xfce4-timer-plugin allows you to set a countdown and an alarm with repeat options if you wish to set it daily for example,:

[image]

It also displays a countdown bar in the panel if you wish:

Countdown running:  [image]

Countdown empty: [image]

You can read more about the plugin in the link above, but, here is the about and usage paragraphs just in case:

> **About**
>
> This is a simple plugin that lets the user run an alarm at a specified
>   time or at the end of a specified countdown period.
>
> **Usage**
>
> The plugin is quite simple – it displays a progressbar showing the
>   percentage of the time elapsed. Left-clicking on the plugin area opens
>   a menu of available alarms. After selecting one, the user can start or
>   stop the timer by selecting “start/stop timer” entry in the same menu.
>   New alarms are added through the preferences window. Each alarm is
>   either a countdown or is run at a specified time. By default a simple
>   dialog pops up at the end of the countdown. The user can choose an
>   external command to be run as the alarm and may also choose to have
>   this repeated a specified number of times with a given interval
>   between repetitions.

Comment: Does this app allow setting a countdown timer to begin automatically at a given time? Is there a way to change the appearance from the bar to a counting timer as the bar isn't very easy to see?

Comment: It seems the alarm is programmable, but the countdown only allows for a duration. As far as I know, there is no option for changing the bar. Can you use Gnome widgets in XFCE for ex.?.

Comment: @Village if i edit this timer plugin to make it handle automatic startup at a given time, would it worth the bounty ?, what's your distro and version of xfce?

Comment: The two problems with the timer app is it is very difficult to see as the little bar is too small, so a count-down clock is better, and it doesn't start autoamtically.

Answer (score 2):

You could use crontab, and a bash script using `yad`.

For example, for a cleanup at 15:10, with countdown beginning at 15:00, and end of class at 18:10 with countdown starting at 18:00:

Create a script for countdown:

```
#!/bin/bash
export max=$1
export action=$2
for i in `seq $max`
do
  echo "$[i* 100/max]"
  echo "#${action} in $[max-i] second" 
  sleep 1
done | yad --on-top --progress --no-buttons --auto-close
```

Edit the crontab of the user who has access to the display (I guess it should be your own user), and adapt the `DISPLAY` variable if `echo $DISPLAY` in your shell is different than `:0`:

`crontab -e`

```
0 15 * * *  DISPLAY=:0 /path/to/script.sh 600 Cleanup
0 18 * * *  DISPLAY=:0 /path/to/script.sh 600 "End of Class"
```